# How to find a basis of $H^2(-N,N)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I need to find an orthonormal basis of $H^2(-N,N)$ where $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $H^2$ denotes the Sobolev space $W^2_2$. I have no idea how to start. A hint to some literatur would be perfect.

Comment: Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214441/orthonormal-basis-for-sobolev-spaces

Comment: Does http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10625-005-0195-1 help?

Comment: @anonymous Not really. That are more complicated spaces and there is no (closed form)-basis given

Comment: What is the norm for which the basis should be orthonormal?

Comment: $\Vert v \Vert_{H^2}^2 = \Vert v \Vert_{L^2}^2 + \Vert Dv \Vert_{L^2}^2 + \Vert D^2v \Vert_{L^2}^2$